# My Tab SM-T380 no longer accepts my PIN

Tags: screen

Set a PIN to unlock my Tab before using. Worked fine for a long time. Today when I enter the PIN it loops back to the enter PIN screen over and over. Tried to reboot but the restart/power off screen loops me back to the enter PIN screen. Tried hard reboot: vol up/power down/home screen. No affect.

Answer (score 1):

Mine did this also. Press and hold the Power button and the Volume button down simultaneously for more than 7 seconds to restart it. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I knew the pin was correct as if I deliberately entered an incorrect pin it came up with the message saying it was incorrect. I tried the reboot too but it doesn't work as the "loop" won't let you turn it off. So I let the battery run down completely (which took a week as it is obviously using very little power; then I found you can have the torch on and that helped the drain). Then once completely dead, plugged in the charger and lo and behold back to normal!

Answer (score 0):

It's a sign of a security thread because the system changed the PIN by itself. wait for 24 hours by removing the battery and try it after the day or just do a factory reset by going on recovery mode.